# Dynamically added attributes don't initialise

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to dynamically add attributes to html elements that are generated and compiled in an `ng-repeat` statement.

I am using the following directive on input elements.

```
.directive('ngLoading', function($compile) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.ngLoading, function() {

         element.attr('ng-required', true);
         element.attr('ng-pattern', '/^[0-9]+$/');

         element.removeAttr('ng-loading');
         $compile(element)(scope);   
    });
  };
});
```

The problem I am seeing is it does in fact add the attribute, be it `ng-required="true"` etc. But it doesn't get initialized by the browser and validation doesn't kick in.

Comment: Curious why you are doing it this way and not having those attributes in the template and simply changing the values in directive? Create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: @charlietfl I am making a form creation tool / editor. Whereby angular generates the element HTML from a json object {type:'text', placeholder:'blah',attributes:[{attr:'ng-required',value:'true'}]} and so forth. I could of course just stick all the attributes on the template and return the value for the attribute, but this would be a messy and non gracious, inflexible solution.

Comment: Create a plunker demo then that reproduces problem. Might also want to look at something like *"angular formly"* for doing this

Comment: Please don't prefix custom directives with the `ng-` prefix. The `ng-` prefix is reserved for core directives. For more information, see [AngularJS Wiki -- Best Practices](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Best-Practices).

Comment: Please include an example HTML for which the `ng-repeat` directive and this custom directive are causing problems..